# How can I move items horizontally in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

Is there any way to move items around (horizontally) and automatically around in a world? I'd like to use it for a farm I have!

Comment: Like on a conveyor belt?

Comment: could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: yeah conveyorbelt would be cool, but im wondering (even with mods) to move items around in a world without the player doing anything.I would be using this for an insanly huge farm im planning to make to power my coin gun

Comment: I'd imagine you may be able to make a conveyor belt of sorts using water and in/out pipes

Comment: The thing is i want to move items, and i dont think items are really affected by anything... then again i dont know

Comment: @Katustrawfic Water doesn't flow in Terraria; there is no direction water will travel in, and you could technically move things vertically (since objects are affected by gravity) but the OP specifically wants a horizontal way of doing it.

Comment: @qwazwak As far as I know, I'm highly doubtful there is a way to move items horizontally

Answer (score 5):

All "Items" that lay around like dropped gold coins respond only to gravity.
The only way to move them is by creating wired wall on the ground and deactivate them, so the item will fall.

I don't know of any way to move or push items in an other direction than down.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [conveyor belts](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Conveyor_Belt) (sold by the Steampunker) to move items, or construct an [item hoik](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Hoik#Item_Hoiks) if you also want to filter what items you move.

Do note that some items cannot be moved by item hoiks.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! It may be worthwhile to explain what an item "hoik" is in this answer, as it's not been explained by any of the other answers, and it is certainly an interesting invention. That aside, conveyor belts have certainly been added since this question was posted, and it's definitely worth mentioning them here. Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can't move items automatically, but you can move yourself to the items automatically. If you set up a minecart track, using bumpers at the end, you can hold one key and move along the minecart track. Some autoclickers are able to hold a key for you.

You can then use minions or lava across the ground to kill the mobs, or a weapon with an autoclicker.

If you don't trust an autoclicker, you can use an autoswing weapon and sticky tape down your left mouse button; in controls you can assign right click to a movement key and tape it down too and that will keep your character moving.

Comment: You don't even need to hold the key. Once you start moving in a minecraft, you have infinite inertia, and will never slow down.